# Configuring clusters : small vs large executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say we have 5 worker machines. Each worker node has configuration of `16 core` and `64 GB`  memory. So Total `80 core` and `320 GB` memory.

Now we can configure the properties as below:

- option-1: set large executor

  - 1 executor per 1 machine, ie. each executor having 63 GB memory and 15 core (removing os/overhead etc)
- option-2: set 5 core per executor

  - number of cores per executors : 5
  - number of executors per machine : 15 core / 5 = 3
  - memory per executor : 63 GB / 3 executor = 21 GB
  - what are the pro and cons of option-1 vs option-2? which is generally recommended?